# Dynamic URLs in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

**Background**

I'm building a course catalog for a school and am trying to make friendly, dynamic URLs. It has three custom post types:

- catalog.
- course. This post type contains a title, course number, and course description.
- section. This post type contains a cost, start and end dates and times, etc. A section is an instance of a course; for example, there might be two sections of Drawing for Beginners, one on Thursday morning and one on Monday night and taught by two different faculty.

There is a one-to-many relationship between course and section. When viewing a section, it displays the parent course's course name, course number, and course description. It also displays that section's cost, start and end dates and times, etc.

The current URL for a section is this:

http://website.org/section/section-slug/

I would like it to be this:

http://website.org/class/spring-2019/drawing-for-beginners/01/

...where "class" is a 'virtual' folder / synthetic prefix
...where "spring-2019" corresponds to a "catalog" custom post type
...where "drawing-for-beginners" corresponds to a slug for the parent "course" custom post type
...where "01" corresponds to the section of the course.

WordPress should display the section post type that matches these criteria.

**Research**

I've read quite a bit about both the Rewrite API and the Endpoints API. The best article I could find on a topic closest to what I'm trying to accomplish is [this one](https://roots.io/routing-wp-requests/). Sadly, the example code on the page didn't work for me, resulting in a "too many redirects error." I can provide more details about exactly which portion didn't work, if desired. I also read [this article on Make WordPress Plugins](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) but it doesn't cover dynamic lookups.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

http://website.org/class/spring-2019/drawing-for-beginners/01/

When the virtual URL is supplied to WordPress, I need the system to perform a query to look up the section whose number is "01" and which belongs to the "spring-2019" catalog and whose parent course has a slug of "drawing-for-beginners." That query isn't a challenge, it's all of the hooks that need to be called to execute that code and return the correct template (for the section page). I'm not sure whether I need to create an Endpoint or can just get away with adding rewrite rules.

Can someone offer some guidance?

--

As a "bonus," I'm also trying to accomplish this:

http://website.org/class/spring-2019/drawing-for-beginners/01/faculty_name

...where "faculty_name" is dynamic and is the name of the person teaching that section (and corresponds to a "faculty" custom post type).

http://website.org/class/spring-2019/drawing-for-beginners/01/gallery

...where "gallery" is a static name and shows a gallery custom post type.

Answer (score 2):

After much investigation, I've found an answer to my question. Here it goes.

This is how to create truly dynamic URLs / slugs in WordPress. The URLs don't correspond to a page. Instead, the parts of the slug are used to look up a post ID and then render that post accordingly.

## Step 1: Add the rewrite rule

```
function pce_rewrite_rules ( ) {
  add_rewrite_rule ( '^class/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=section&catalog_name=$matches[1]&course_name=$matches[2]&section_no=$matches[3]','top' ) ;
add_action ( 'init', 'pce_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 ) ;
```

## Step 2: Register the query variables

```
function pce_register_query_vars ( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'course_name';
    $vars[] = 'catalog_name';
    $vars[] = 'section_no';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter ( 'query_vars', 'pce_register_query_vars' );
```

## Step 3: Modify the WP query

Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query. But you have to force some variables in the query so that WordPress loads the template that you need. To find the variables I needed to manually set, I used a WP plugin (Query Monitor) to examine the contents of the WP query, and I used `var_dump` on the type of post I wanted to "copy."

```
function pce_dynamic_section_lookup ( $wp ) {

    if ( is_admin() || ! $wp->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }

    if ( $wp->is_main_query() ) {
        // Only defined if we're looking at a "fake" URL.
        // Example: http://pce.local/class/spring-2019/handmade-books/01/
        if ( get_query_var ('course_name' ) ) {
            // These are some of the variables I needed to set manually.
            $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = 'section' ;
            $wp->query_vars['is_single'] = true ;
            $wp->query_vars['is_singular'] = true;
            $wp->query_vars['is_archive'] = false;

            $course_name = get_query_var ('course_name' ) ;
            $catalog_name = get_query_var ('catalog_name' ) ;
            $section_no = get_query_var ('section_no' ) ;

            // More code is here to look up the post ID I need.

            // Set the post ID here. This makes the magic happen.
            $wp->query_vars['p'] = $post_id ;

            // This also makes the magic happen. It forces the template I need to be selected.
            $wp->is_single = true ;
            $wp->is_singular = true ;
            $wp->is_archive = false ;
            $wp->is_post_type_archive = false ;
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', 'pce_dynamic_section_lookup', 0, 2 ) ;
```

I had a post with this original URL:

http://pce.local/section/handmade-books-01/

And now I can load it at this URL (and it *loads* it, it does not forward it):

http://pce.local/class/spring-2019/handmade-books/01/

I needed to do this because multiple sections are going to be added in future catalogs and I wanted to keep the URLs friendly. In the summer if the class is offered, it will be...

http://pce.local/class/summer-2019/handmade-books/01/

Instead of...

http://pce.local/section/handmade-books-01-2/

or whatever slug WordPress assigns it. Having only a couple of sections isn't a big deal, but there will be several in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood good, this might help you. 
I am not sure how did you make relationship but i will put the code that i usually use. And lets say that catalog-course also have a  relationship.

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{

    $section_rules = array(
        'class/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $section_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function change_section_links($post_link, $id=0){

    $courses = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'post__in' => get_post_meta( $catalog_id, '_course', true ),
    ) );

    if ( $courses-> have_posts() ) { while ( $courses->have_posts() ) {
          $courses->the_post();
          $catalog_name = get_the_title();  
        }

    $sections = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'section',
        'post__in' => get_post_meta( $course_id, '_section', true ),
    ) );

        if ( $sections-> have_posts() ) { while ( $sections->have_posts() ) {
                  $sections->the_post();
                  $course_name = get_the_title();  
            }

    $post = get_post($id);

    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'section'){
        return home_url('/class/'. $catalog_name. '/'. $course_name. '/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_section_links', 1, 3);
```

I hope that it would help you. If it doesnt, tell me how did you make relationship.

Comment: In answer to your first question, you're correct in your new formulation of the URL. In terms of how can I display the URL of 1 course, there is only 1 section with one section number for a course in a given catalog. For example, there is only one Drawing for Beginners (section 01) in the spring catalog. (There may also be a section 02 of Drawing for Beginners.) Does this answer your question?

Comment: If details in your slug are not title of post, you can call another function. If you are using ACF it would be get the field..

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It appears this code is trying to change the permalink. That's not quite what I need to accomplish, strangely enough. I'm seeking a kind of alternate URL, or alias, for each page. And this alias ought to display the page, not forward to the "original" page / slug.

You asked how I created a relationship between posts. I'm using a commercial plugin named Toolset Types (https://toolset.com). It allows you to create relationships among posts (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many).

Comment: I ended up finding a solution. I'll post it for posterity soon.