# How to make dynamic URL based on Users Country

Tags: wordpress, url, dynamic-url

I want to show the dynamic URL of few pages in wordpress. For example if user views a page from FLORIDA then the URL should look like the following:
https://example.com/learn/**florida**/actual_page_url

Can someone tell me, if is it possible to create such dynamic URLs in Wordpress?

I tried different plugins for this, even did some code in function.php file, but nothing happened.

Comment: It's possible to do it, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/54994965/4906348